# Cheap Flights Project / Button element return 'NoneType' object error Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a small Selenium side project which will help me find cheap flights whenever wherever.
I have a problem with a Button element. Can't make it work.

Code: https://github.com/johnnybigH/wizzscrap

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


class wizzScrap:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.driver = None
        self.url = url
        self.by = None
        self.value = None

        self.web_element = None
        # self.find()


    def setUpDriver(self):
        #  Set up driver
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
        options.add_argument('--incognito')
        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation" :2}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome( 
                "/Users/adamke/Downloads/chromedriver", 
                options=options)
        return self.driver


    def startDriver(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)


    def find(self, by, value):
        element = WebDriverWait(
            self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, value)))
        self.web_element = element
        return None        


    def inputText(self, text):
        return self.web_element.send_keys(text)


    def click(self, by, value):
        element = WebDriverWait(
            self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, value)))
        self.web_element = element
        element.click()
        return self.web_element


    def text(self):
        text = self.web_element.text
        return text


    def switch_tabs(self):
        #  Close unneded tab and focus on the main one
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

        mainWindow = self.driver.window_handles[1]  #  Thats the Tab we want
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.switch_to.window(mainWindow)


    def isElementPresent(self, by, value):
        try:
            self.find(by, value)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            result = False
        else: 
            result = True
        print(result)


    def closeDriver(self):
        self.driver.quit()


    def getDestArriv(self):
        #  Choose the Origin and Destination for your fly
        try:
            #  Origin
            self.click(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-departure-station']")
            self.inputText('Katowice')
            self.click(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
            "strong[class='locations-container__location__name']")
            #  Arrival
            self.click(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-arrival-station']")
            self.inputText('malaga')
            self.click(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
            "strong[class='locations-container__location__name']")
            #  Start searching
            self.click(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-test='flight-search-submit']")
        except Exception:
            print('Thats shitty code man, work on it!')



    def parse(self):
        self.setUpDriver()
        self.startDriver()
        self.getDestArriv()

        # Switch to the Tab that contains tickets prices for next few days
        self.switch_tabs()

        # Button "Next"
        self.isElementPresent(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="outbound-fare-selector"]/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]')
        self.click(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="outbound-fare-selector"]/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]')


url = 'https://wizzair.com'
Page = wizzScrap(url)
Page.parse()
Page.closeDriver()
```

After choosing airports I am switching to the Tab that contain tickets prices for the next few days. There are two buttons "previous" and "next".
Both return empty or NonType.

**This is the Element I have problem with.**
xpath for "button next":

```
self.click(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="outbound-fare-selector"]/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]')
```

The function "self.isElementPresent" returned True so the element exists.

I tried to interact with it by.Xpath, CSS_SELECTOR, (x,y location), ActionChain and some other methods but nothing is working.
I also get returned 96 elements by doing:

```
button_test = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
    collection_of_buttons = []
    for button in button_test:
        collection_of_buttons.append(button)

    for button in collection_of_buttons:
        print(button)
```

which is the same number I get in the browser console so looks like nothing is hidden if I understand well.
I also tried by execute_script but that didn't work as well.

I have no more ideas so will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? Relevant HTML?? Public URL???

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: @DebanjanB the URL is in the code on the bottom... the issue is the `return None` in the `find` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works:

```
self.driver.execute_script("return 
document.getElementsByClassName('flight-select__flight-date-picker__button 
flight-select__flight-date-picker__button--next')[0].click();")
```

Comment: This will work but it is not "best practice"... you can use `ActionChains` I'll edit it into my answer...

Comment: @MosheSlavin I know what you mean... What i have read is I shouldnt do that when it comes to the testing, but thats only for my own use so just wanna make it works

Answer (score 0):

Your method `find` always returns None hence the error `'NoneType' object`:

```
def find(self, by, value):
    element = WebDriverWait(
        self.driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, value)))
    self.web_element = element
    return None
```

What you should be doing is returning the element...

```
def find(self, by, value):
    element = WebDriverWait(
        self.driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, value)))
    self.web_element = element
    return self.web_element # or return element
```

Also, change the XPath to be more robust use:

```
# Button "Next"
self.click(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="flight-select__flight-date-picker__button flight-select__flight-date-picker__button--next"]')
```

## Edit:

You can use `ActionChains` to click with offset:

```
button_element = self.find(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="flight-select__flight-date-picker__button flight-select__flight-date-picker__button--next"]')
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(button_element, 5, 5).click().perform()
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I didint see that... thanks much appreciated. But even that, its still not working. Iam getting that error: `</button> is not clickable at point (1375, 337). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loader-combined">` Looks like its covered with some other element if Iam right

Comment: @johnnybigH yes it is covered with an element... You can try playing around with the position of the click... I don't know if it will help... I'm glad you got it to work with JS....